# Find $F'(x)$ where $F(t) := \int_{g(x)}^0 f(x,t)dt$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

> Let $f: \mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ also $C^1$. Define
>   $$F(t) := \int_{g(x)}^0 f(x,t)dt$$
>   Find $F'(x)$.

What I did was first define $\Phi : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^3$ as follow
$$t \mapsto (g(t),t,0)$$
and $\varphi : \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ as

$$(u, t, v) \mapsto \int_u^v f(x,t)dt$$
Then, when taking the composit $\varphi \circ \Phi$, we get

$$(\varphi \circ \Phi)(t)= \varphi (\Phi(t))=\varphi(g(t),t,0)= \int_{g(t)}^0f(x,t)dt= F(x)$$
So $F$ is differentiableand by the chain rule

$$F'(x)=J_F(x)=J_{\varphi \circ \Phi}(x)=J_{\varphi}(\Phi(x))J_{\Phi}(x)$$
That last expression equals to (developing the jacobian matrix)

$$-f(x,g(x))g'(x)+\int_{g(t)}^0\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,t)dt$$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: It is perfectly correct and well explained to me.

Comment: it seems ok to me although the last variable v is unnecessary.